# Android ShareActionProvider Set Text Color

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-sharing

Is there a style that works with the Android ShareActionProvider that allows the text to be white instead of black.  I have tried:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/menu_color</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceListItem">@style/menu_color</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceListItemSmall">@style/menu_color</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/menu_color</item>`
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyShareActionProviderStyle</item>`
<item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/MyShareActionProviderStyle</item>`
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/share_item_color</item>
```

I have tried all of these properties in a number of different configurations and cannot seem to  find the right property to change to get the text to be the correct color.

I am using a Holo theme base and I am not using AppCompat or ActionBarSherlock.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for this. I also have same issue, I am using support:appcompat-v7:22

Comment: @Max just posted an answer to my question that might help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found one more solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

First I created a subclass of `ShareActionProvider` and set that in the menu xml file for that fragment as the `android:actionProviderClass`

Then in the `onCreateActionView` of that `ShareActionProvider` subclass i did this:

```
View v = super.onCreateActionView();
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
    TextView title = (TextView)nextChild.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if(title != null){
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
return v;
```

That got me the text of the menu white like I needed.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using toolbar you don't need to extend ShareActionProvider. Only you need to apply theme in toolabr `app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"`

And here is the theme code

```
<style name="toolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: As I said in my question I wasn't using AppCompat so when I tried this it didn't work.